# Copy file to relative path boost c++

Tags: c++, boost

I'm working on a program where I let the user import images to the program and then when the user decides to save all imported images are supposed to be copied to another folder for easy access the next time the user wants to use the program.

```
try
{
    copy_file(image_files[i], p); 
}
catch(const filesystem_error& ex)
{
    cout << ex.what() << endl;
}
```

The error I'm getting is that the path cannot be find. The images paths are all in absoulute form and I would like to copy them to a relative path that is the programs directory.

Comment: It's likely that the relative path is wrong compared to the applications working directory. Print out the applications working directory, and the relative path, and make sure that the relative path is correct.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Hmm, using current_path it tells me it's in the folder where the image I'm trying to copy is stored. Then I can see why it fails to find the path but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Change the relative path to `./`?

Comment: You're not mistaking `.` for `..`? `.` is the *current* directory (which was where you wanted to copy the files to?) and `..` is the parent directory.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg then I get an error saying that the file already exists.